# How to embed font-awesome icons in a navbar link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, font-awesome

How can I go about embedding font-awesome icons into my Ruby <%= link_to code?

The below does NOT work, is it possible to accomplish the below some how so that it actually works?

```
 <li><%= link_to "<span class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-1x"></span> Settings</span>", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
```

Thanks!
Johnson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you try this:

```
<li><%= link_to your_path do %><span class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-1x"></span> Settings <% end %></li>
```

for instance with font-awesome in some of my codes:

```
<li><%= link_to edit_contact_path(@contact) do %><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit<% end %></li>


<li><%= link_to @contact, method: :delete, data:{confirm: "Delete this contact?"} do %><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Delete<% end %></li>
```

Here is the documentation, see the section with link_to ... do .... end
[link to documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Answer (score 1):

I've always done it including the class in the Ruby code like this,

```
<li><%= link_to " Sign Up", '#', class: "fa fa-user-plus" %></li>
```

This includes the icon on the left of the text so you have to include the space preceding "Sign up" in order to get it to look right.

Answer (score 0):

Better option for you is use this gem:
https://github.com/h4b00/awesome_link

After installation you can simply use(for example):

```
<%= awesome_link('fa-pencil-square-o', root_path, method: :update) %>
```